# Where do i add the begin at zero (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've made two charts, one line chart and one bar-chart, that you can switch between and the charts contains different data.  The problem is that I can't seem to make them begin at zero? Where in the script do I put the code so both charts begin at zero, because now it just doesn't work or the whole bar just disappears.

```
    <script> 

                let lineConfig = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"],
      datasets: [{
          label: "Miljoner ton", 
        data: [56.38, 59.3, 61.81, 58.83, 52.32, 66.86],
           lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)",
        borderColor: "green", // The main line color
        borderCapStyle: 'square',
        pointBorderColor: "white",
        pointBackgroundColor: "green",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "green",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,

      }]
    }

                },





                barConfig = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Palmolja', "Sojaolja", 'Animaliskt fett', 'Solrosolja', 'Rapsolja', 'Annat'],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Procent",
          data: [28.6, 25.3, 13.2, 8.0, 12.2, 9.6],
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)",
        borderColor: "green", // The main line color
        borderCapStyle: 'square',
        pointBorderColor: "white",
        pointBackgroundColor: "green",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "green",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,


      }]
    }
  },
  activeType = 'bar', // we'll start with a bar chart.
  myChart;

function init(config) {
  // create a new chart with the supplied config.
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
}

// first init as a bar chart.
init(barConfig);

document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // every time the button is clicked we destroy the existing chart.
  myChart.destroy();
  if (activeType == 'bar') {
    // chart was a bar, init a new line chart.
    activeType = 'line';
    init(lineConfig);
    return;
  }

  // chart was a line, init a new bar chart.
  activeType = 'bar';
  init(barConfig);
});

            </script>
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b4d5y01z/

Comment: [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/b4d5y01z/1/) as per my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641595/3775731).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean for your linear y-axis then the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html?h=beginatzero#tick-configuration-options) specifies the following:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

***Edit as per [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641204/where-do-i-add-the-begin-at-zero-chart-js/52641595#comment92215756_52641595):***

The `options` property is a sibling of `type` and `data`, e.g.:

```
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [...],
    datasets: [{
      data: [...]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where I should put it